# How to extract data from a feeder on gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm new with gatling and I have problem that I can't resolve by myself. I have to extract values from feeder I created, but I don't have idea how to do. Do you have any ideas how to do this? Thanks for your help.

```
val feeder = csv("insertPC.csv").random
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this in your CSV:

```
computer
Macbook
MacBook Pro
```

It would be something like this:

```
 object Search {

  val feeder = csv("insertPC.csv").random 
  val search = exec(http("Search")
         .feed(feeder)
        .get("/computers?f=${computer}");
 }
```

Notice the matching between **CSV first row** which is column name and **${computer}**

Comment: you would also need to call .feed(feeder) to actually populate the session  value for 'computer'